# Image segmentation with 3 classes but one of them is easy to find, How can I write the network to not train on the easy one?

Tags: python-2.7, keras, neural-network, image-segmentation

I am using *MS-D* or *UNet* network for image segmentation. My image has three classes: noise, signal and empty. The class empty is easy to find because the pixel values for the empty class is mainly -1 while for the two other classes is between 0-1.

Is there a way that I only ask the network to find noise and signal class and not bother the network about the easy one? Or any other clue that can help? I am seeing that the network sometimes is confused when predicting the signal pixels and gives about the same score but with higher to the signal class (e.g. empty0.0001, noise0.0003, signal0.0005) to all three classes. I want to make it easier for the network to figure it out.

Just more information about my image, around 25% of pixels are signal, 40% noise, and 35% are empty. I am using `dice_coef` for the metric and loss function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that. I think You should apply some regularization and/or dropout to the network and feed it more data.

But what you could do is to label all the empty pixels as `noise` as `signal` is usually in the middle and `noise` is on the outer side of the signal graph. Then you train the network that way. You will have to set network outputs to 2: `noise` or `signal`. From the original image you know which pixels were `empty` and then you can set those pixels from `noise` to `empty`. Then you will have the result you wanted.

The only thing that can happen here is that the  network will perform bad because of the imbalanced classes as you will have much more `noise` than `signal` pixels.

Comment: I tried it and the network works very bad if I only have two classes, exactly because of the imbalance classes. That is why I thought might be a way to makes it easy for the network about one of the classes.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything you can do about that. Try making your network more robust, augment the data to create more samples so the network will have more to learn from.